Short story about a man born in a society of inductive reasoning, who steals a rocket to escape
It was a short story; would have been published most likely 1950s-1980s.
He's born almost as an evolutionary throwback, being only able to use deductive reasoning in a society where mankind has evolved to use inductive reasoning & intuitively solve problems.
He's pitied and I think he works as janitor in a museum as it's the only job he's suited for.
In the end, he steals an old museum mothballed spaceship/rocket to seek a new life and it's revealed the authorities set it all up so he could do so as a kindness.

"Kindness" by Lester del Rey (Astounding, October 1944) is the story, and it's available here.
Last homo sapiens:

Homo sapiens! In the dim, remote days when his ancestors had owned
the world, they had made jokes about it, shortening it to “homo sap,”
and laughing, because they’d known no other species to rival them. It
was no longer a joke Homo intelligens was now the master, and he was
only a living fossil painfully aware that the old pun had become
reality. Danny was the last man in a world of supermen


Inductive Reasoning:

Homo sapiens had invented reason to replace the uncertain
trial-and-error thinking of the other animals, and had ruled supreme
for a million years. Now homo intelligens had replaced that with full
intuition that leaped from fact to condusion without going through the
painful intermediate steps of reasoning, and the new supremacy was
his.


Arranged "Escape"

Poor kid, I’d begun to think we waited too long, and that he never
would make it. Another six months—and he’d have died like a flower out
of the sun! Yet I was sure it would work when Miss Larsen showed me
that story, with its mythical planetoid-paradises. A rather clever
story, if you like pseudohistory; I hope the one I prepared was its
equal.”

Kindness:

“Kindness, Kindness to repay with a few million credits and a few
thousands of hours of work— plus a lie here and there—for all that we
owe the boy’s race!” The professor’s voice was tired, as he dumped the
contents of his pipe into a snuffer, and strode over slowly toward the
great window that looked out on the night sky. “I wonder, sometimes,
Bryant, what kindness Neanderthaler found when the last one came to
die. Or whether the race that will follow us when the darkness falls
on us will have something better than such kindness.”


Fascinating. I've long noted this weird trend in mid-20th c. SF that holds out "intuition" as a kind of magical superpower. This reference is yet another (fairly early) example.

I think it was an idea that Campbell liked

@Andrew - Along with psychic powers, Dianetics, and the superiority of humans over aliens. And perhaps not so coincidentally, the superiority of White Americans over Black Americans and all the other branches of humanity, and men over women. Quite a charming fellow, that Campbell. The roots of modern science fiction, it seems, are as dirty as those of anything else....

Scottish/English Americans above most others, too, as I recall.

It seems an update in the basics of logic are needed! It is in fact only rarely used properly by humans who reason in some mix of low-energy, flaky ad-hoc logic (due to evident computational limits) + somewhat probabilistic reasoning (because one needs to perform a lot more evaluation than logic alone can provide). Anyway for "logic" we have this: Deduction, Induction, Abduction

John Barnes wrote a novel with abduction (in the logical sense) as a key feature.
